# Higher NDVI than SAVI

Tags: ndvi, landsat-8, toa-calibration

I have calculated NDVI and SAVI for landsat-8 image. But I am getting higher value of NDVI than SAVI Can you tell me reason for this NDVI=0.46 SAVI=0.34 Specific band pixel values are toa b4- 0.130 toa b5- 0.365 L= 0.5 taken

Comment: I don't get it. From [SAVI description](http://wiki.landscapetoolbox.org/doku.php/remote_sensing_methods:soil-adjusted_vegetation_index), I don't see why SAVI should be always superior to NDVI?

Answer (score 3):

The formula for SAVI is:

```
SAVI = (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED + L) * (1 + L)
```

The formula for NDVI is:

```
NDVI = (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)
```

From these formulas, it is clear that, depending on the values that you put in, either one can be higher than the other. In this case, you entered `RED = 0.13` & `NIR = 0.365` & `L = 0.5`.
This gives us `SAVI = (0.365 - 0.130) / (0.365 + 0.130 + 0.5) * (1 + 0.5) = 0.354` & `NDVI = (0.365 - 0.130) / (0.365 + 0.130) = 0.475`.

All in all, it appears that your calculations are correct. Furthermore, your input values also appear sane, which brings us to the end: NDVI can be higher than SAVI.

Comment: Values given are of wheat plot when crop is at development stage. I have studied ground spectrometer data it alway show higher SAVI than NDVI. So mean that soil adjusted value should higher know??

Comment: @user68684, your calculations are correct, which must then mean that you either have atmospheric noise, or simply not calibrated your data correctly.